# How to re-order the activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have 3 activity.For example a,b,c. I created a first and then b and then c.
I want to run the b activity first. How to reorder the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch any activity first,it's not up to creation time its dependent
on how you specify in

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

for more detail you can review this example
[AndroidManifest](https://developer.android.com/samples/BorderlessButtons/AndroidManifest.html)

here's a sample code to launch activity first

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="BActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="AActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="CActivity"/>
</application>
```